# $(...).lightSlider is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added all required js and css files, still getting this error. I am sharing my header script : It's a jquery slider plugin I have downloaded from github and trying to integrate in a laravel web application

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/bootcamp.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/lightslider.css')}}">

<style>
    .bootcamp-body{
        background: white;
        color: black;
    }

    .content{
    }

    .content-slider{
        list-style: none outside none;
        padding-left: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .demo .item{
        margin-bottom: 60px;
    }
    .content-slider li{
        background-color: #ed3020;
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFF;
    }
    .content-slider h3 {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 70px 0;
    }
    .demo{
        width: 800px;
    }
 </style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='{{asset('js/lightslider.js')}}'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content-slider").lightSlider({
        loop:true,
        keyPress:true
    });
    $('#image-gallery').lightSlider({
        gallery:true,
        item:1,
        thumbItem:9,
        slideMargin: 0,
        speed:500,
        auto:true,
        loop:true,
        onSliderLoad: function() {
            $('#image-gallery').removeClass('cS-hidden');
        }
     });
  });
</script>
```

I am getting the following error :
[image]

[image]

The library looks (after clicking on the link) :

[image]

Comment: can you share the library link?

Comment: I already did :) <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: no this is jquery, I'm asking for lightslider library link

Comment: here : http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/

Comment: I am using lightslider library just after the jquery library

Comment: The library isn't loaded. The file might not be present in the specified dir. Could you open the web page view source code and then click on the library link and see what is shows ? is it 404 or does the library then load

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234491/discussion-between-sid-and-azim).

Comment: are you running all this on localhost?

Comment: @techie_28 yes, I am doing it in localhost

Comment: could you for once try it with jQuery v1.11.0 (as used in the demo) instead of v3.5.1?.. clear the cache & reload the page

Comment: also it is possible that lightslider.js is being blocked by your browser as it is not on https(Check for browser's indicators which are generally present on the address bar, represented by Icons like Shield & Lock ) or load it via CDN (https://cdnjs.com/libraries/lightslider) to see if it works.

Comment: I tried with older js version as well, Ok trying the cdn version

Comment: @azim copy everything in the file `lightslider.js` and insert it in inside script tag just after you jQuery include. Make sure you remove this line `<script src='{{asset('js/lightslider.js')}}'></script>`  Lets see if its an issue with the include.